# Use PHP sessions with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, session

Well, my question is simple:

I wish to use my PHP sessions in jQuery, in an if statement, however I do not know how I can do this on an easy way. Am I supposed to somehow import the `$_SESSION` in jquery?

What I basically want to do, is open a dialog if the User_ID is the same as the `$_SESSION` User_ID. Also I wish to have it checked to see if someone is an administrator, shop-manager or a user, with the session. This information already exists in PHP and the User_ID only exists in jQuery.

```
if($admin == true || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id']){
   Javascript code here?
}
```

I think that would be the easiest way to solve it, however that does not seem to work for me. Perhaps I am forgetting tags for the PHP to understand it's javascript?

I've figured out an easy way to come around the solution, thanks you you all!

Solution:

```
$('.do').click(function(){
  <?php
    if ($admin == true) {
        echo "$('#dialog').dialog('open');\n";
        echo "var cid = $(this).attr('id');\n";
        echo "var datum = cid.substr(0, 10);\n";
        echo "var naampos = cid.indexOf('|');\n";
        echo "var gebridpos = cid.indexOf('||');\n";
        echo "var naam = cid.substring(naampos+1,gebridpos);\n";
        echo "var gebrid = cid.substring(gebridpos+2);\n";
        echo "$.ajax({\n";
        echo "type: \"POST\",\n";
        echo "url: \"agenda.php\",\n";
        echo "data: naam,\n";
        echo "success: function(){\n";
        echo "$('#gebruikerinput').html(\"<input type='text' READONLY='' size='35' value='\" + naam +\"'>\");\n";
        echo "$('#gebridinput').html(\"<input type='hidden' name='gebridtextbox' value='\" + gebrid + \"'>\");\n";
        echo "$('#datuminput').html(\"<input type='text' READONLY='' size='12' name='datum' value='\" + datum + \"'>\");\n";
        echo "}\n";
        echo "})\n";
        echo "return false;\n";
    }
  ?>
});
```

It seems to be working so far. The only thing left for me to do is to make so jQuery returns a User_ID variable which needs to be identical to the session ID.

Comment: if $admin return a boolean value,plase,use if($admin || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id'])

Comment: You can always mix JavaScript code inside PHP and vice-versa. But be aware that JavaScript runs on the browser thus it can be tampered with.

Comment: In your solution code, you check if the user is an admin before echoing out the JQuery code, which then does an Ajax call to a PHP script.  So, why would you not simply check the user is an admin in the agenda.php script?  There should not need to be any user auth stuff handled in the JQuery, since you can store the user id and whether the user is an admin in the $_SESSION[], PHP side.  The browser will pass the PHP session cookie as a header with the AJAX request - take a look at headers sent on the wire with a Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($admin == true || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id']){
$javascript = "javascript code here";
}
```

and then in your html

```
<body>
<?php echo $javascript ?>
</body>
```

Comment: An important thing yo point out here is that this solution will only send the JS code to the correct users. If you where to send the code, and then let the JS work out if it should be run or not, you are open to possibility the user edits the JS so that it runs when didn't want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import the $_SESSION, but you can store some of them (only those that you want) in the cookie and read it in javascript.

For example: store the user-id in the cookie and you can read the value from the cookie in javascript.

read cookie:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: or, if you wanted a session from php into javascript you could just do this

<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>

Comment: Actually, I'd have thought the easiest way would be to serialize it as JSON: `echo 'var json="' . json_encode($_SESSION). '";'`.  This way, he could use `var obj = JSON.parse(json);` and would have the PHP session available as a Javascript structure.  Not that this is a very good approach in general...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly that you can mix server-side script (PHP) with client-side script (Javascript). However, you can use PHP to `echo` Javascript, like:

```
if ($admin == true || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id']){
    echo '<script>
               alert("Admin!");
               $("selector").function(); //
          </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Php is a server side language. javascript runs on the browser (client side).You can do this:

```
if($admin == true || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id'])
echo "<script>";
echo "here your jquery function";
echo "</script>";
```

}

So that you're just rendering HTML

hope it helps

Comment: you're welcome! Please mark the answer as the one you choose! =P

Comment: Yihka is saying that gebr_id is a variable in Javascript, not in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if($admin == true || gebr_id == $_SESSION['id']){ ?>
        alert('<?php print $admin; ?>');
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

also works.

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing the apparently obvious security flaws with what you seem to be suggesting, you want to output the PHP session ID to your web page.  Of course, JQuery is a client-side language, and it's pretty trivial to circumvent any client-side security of that nature.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
//put in your variables from PHP
echo 'var phpId="' . $_SESSION['id'] .'";' ."\n";
echo 'var admin=' .$admin.";\n";
?>
//Back to Javascript (client side) here
if (gebr_id == phpId || admin){
   ...
}
</script>
```

You say you only have the user ID in JQuery.  What you should do is code it so you have the user id available in PHP instead...  Submit a form with the user id or something like that, then you can store that in the PHP session and do your authentication server-side.

Comment: I will be checking the Session ID with the user ID in the jquery,so even if the user is able to manipulate the user ID in the jquery, the user is not able to use it, since only he can do anything with it as long as it is identical with his session ID. The user ID will probably be sent as some sort of variable to PHP.

Comment: So, if you echo your PHP session ID out onto the page, I as a user can see it, and I can manipulate the javascript using something like Firebug so that the two variables are equal.  Then I will trigger whatever it is you're trying to hide.  Do the security stuff server-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get access to PHP Sessions from javascript, you can write a simple wrapper.

Somethign like this:

```
<?php
session_start($_GET['sid']);
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

Keep in mind that this is a **possible security flaw**, as everyone can get access to your PHP Session variables from outside (with a valid session id).

Now you can simply use jQuery to ask the server for the current session data